# Area under curve

Tags: curves

Find the area bounded by the curve $y = x e^{–x}$ ; xy = 0 and x = c where c is the x-coordinate of the curve's inflection point.
The answer is $1-3e^{-2}$

I tried to plot the curve in desmos.com. xy=0 is a straight line. The point of infection of the curve is x=1 and $\infty$.

Comment: $xy=0$ are the $x$ axis and $y$ axis.

Comment: xy=0 is coming as straight line y=0 in desmos.com, even if I consider xy=0 as straight line y=0 , point of inflection y'=$e^{-x}(-x+1)=0$ we get point of inflection as 1 & $\infty$

Comment: Put xy=0 in desmos.com and see the curve

Comment: Regarding $c$ point - the answer will contains this variable $c$. are you sure there is a $c$ or a known value?

Comment: 'c' is the point of inflection, we need to find that c=2

Comment: c=2 by second deravative hence answer is proved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$xy=0$ is not a straight line: it is the union of two straight lines, viz. the coordinate axes.

I cannot understand why you assert that $x=\infty$ gives an inflection point. Neither do I get $c=1$ as the $x$-coordinate of the curve's inflection point. (What is the second derivative of $xe^{-x}$?)

The region between the curve, $xy=0$ and $x=c$ is the set
$\{(x,y):0\le x\le c,0\le y\le xe^{-x}\}$ and has area
$$\int_0^c xe^{-x}\,dx=\left[-(x+1)e^{-x}\right]_0^c=1-(c+1)e^{-c}$$
which gives a further clue as to the correct value of $c$.